# wait for arrays to be filled with ajax results

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make my page wait untill all data is loaded and put into the right arrays. I load the data using 3 seperate ajax calls but since the loading sometimes takes a little too long, the page continues while having empty arrays, and I need this data before I can do anything on the page.

I've been looking into the `jQuery.when` function but I can't seem to get it working.

this is 1 of the ajax calls:

```
function getWerktijden(){
    var AllArrays = [];
    var dagen = [];
    var start = [];
    var end = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("getWerktijden")',
        data: {
            id: @Model.ID,
            dag: d,
            maandNr: m,
            jaarNr: y,
            getJson: true,
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //console.log(result);
            for(var v = 0; v < result.length; v++){
                var resultItem = result[v];

                var ingangsDatum = resultItem.activatieDatum;
                var uitgangsDatum = resultItem.stopDatum;
                if(ingangsDatum != ""){
                    ingangsDatum = new Date(changeDateTimeFormat(ingangsDatum));
                    ingangsDatum = ingangsDatum.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
                };
                if(uitgangsDatum != ""){
                    uitgangsDatum = new Date(changeDateTimeFormat(uitgangsDatum));
                    uitgangsDatum = uitgangsDatum.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
                };

                dagen.push({
                    werktijdenID: resultItem.id,
                    ingang: ingangsDatum,
                    uitgang: uitgangsDatum,
                    maandag: resultItem.maandag,
                    dinsdag: resultItem.dinsdag,
                    woensdag: resultItem.woensdag,
                    donderdag: resultItem.donderdag,
                    vrijdag: resultItem.vrijdag,
                    zaterdag: resultItem.zaterdag,
                    zondag: resultItem.zondag
                });

                start.push({
                    werktijdenID: resultItem.id,
                    ma_van: resultItem.ma_van,
                    di_van: resultItem.di_van,
                    wo_van: resultItem.wo_van,
                    do_van: resultItem.do_van,
                    vr_van: resultItem.vr_van,
                    za_van: resultItem.za_van,
                    zo_van: resultItem.zo_van,
                })

                end.push({
                    werktijdenID: resultItem.id,
                    ma_tot: resultItem.ma_tot,
                    di_tot: resultItem.di_tot,
                    wo_tot: resultItem.wo_tot,
                    do_tot: resultItem.do_tot,
                    vr_tot: resultItem.vr_tot,
                    za_tot: resultItem.za_tot,
                    zo_tot: resultItem.zo_tot,
                })
            }
        }
    });
    AllArrays.push(dagen, start, end);
    return AllArrays;
};
```

Then I call the function on a variable to return those results into that variable and check wether it's done with the `jQuery.when` function but the page continues no matter if the function has completed.

```
var allArrays = getWerktijden();
var event = getMeldingen(); //I put this here to show I have more ajax calls
var ziektedatums = getZiektedatums(); //I put this here to show I have more ajax calls

$.when.apply($, allArrays, event, ziektedatums).then(function(){
    dagenPerWeek = allArrays[0];
    startPerDag = allArrays[1];
    endPerDag = allArrays[2];
}).done(function(){
    console.log(dagenPerWeek, startPerDag, endPerDag, event, ziektedatums);
});
```

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @Karan Yes I could but I'd rather not since that's going to be deprecated. so that would only be a temporary solution...

Comment: @Karan that is a horrible suggestion and terrible practice and should never ever be used It is also deprecated by browser vendors and displays warnings in console when used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the `$.ajax` promise instead of the array from each function

The array will be immediately returned before the ajax is complete as it is asynchronous. Also an array is not a promise so `$.when` won't wait for it to be populated

It's also easier to use `Promise.all()` vs `$.when()` in modern browsers

So it will look something like:

```
function getWerktijden() {
  var AllArrays = [];
  var dagen = [];
  var start = [];
  var end = [];

  // return the promise
  return $.ajax({ /* config options*/ })
    .then(function(result) {
      // do the processing into various arrays


      // return to be used in next part of promise chain
      return AllArrays;
    });
}



Promise.all([getWerktijden(), getMeldingen(), getZiektedatums()])
       .then(function(results){
          // results will be array of whatever is returned from  `then()`
          // in each function and is in same order as they are called

          var getWerktijden_Arrays = results[0],
              dagenPerWeek = getWerktijden_Arrays[0]

              console.log(dagemPerWeek);
       })
```

Comment: I followed your instructions but no success :( the page still continues whilst the arrays are empty and then at the end of everything it `console.log(dagenPerWeek);`

Comment: Maybe you need to display a loading icon until all data is received. Then hide it in the Promise.all callback

Comment: could it also be because the script that needs those arrays is in a `(document).ready()` ??

Comment: After placing some large parts of the `document.ready` in functions it works! Though I am forced to chain the functions and start the first function at the bottom in the `Promise.all` callback. Thanks!